# GDAL is not adding color relief above a certain elevation

Tags: python, gis, gdal

Generating elevation heatmaps using GDAL for Python, elevations above approximately 200m will not get get a colour assigned:

```py
def get_relevant_dem_files():
    all_files = glob.glob("./data/Maps/ASTER/*.tif")

    return all_files

def get_color_map(min, max, step):
    colors = gdal.ColorTable()
    colors.CreateColorRamp(min, (94, 79, 162), min + step, (50, 136, 189))
    colors.CreateColorRamp(min + step, (50, 136, 189), min + 2 * step, (102, 194, 165))
    colors.CreateColorRamp(
        min + 2 * step, (102, 194, 165), min + 3 * step, (171, 221, 164)
    )
    colors.CreateColorRamp(
        min + 3 * step, (171, 221, 164), min + 4 * step, (230, 245, 152)
    )
    colors.CreateColorRamp(
        min + 4 * step, (230, 245, 152), min + 5 * step, (255, 255, 191)
    )
    colors.CreateColorRamp(
        min + 5 * step, (255, 255, 191), min + 6 * step, (254, 224, 139)
    )
    colors.CreateColorRamp(
        min + 6 * step, (254, 224, 139), min + 7 * step, (253, 174, 97)
    )
    colors.CreateColorRamp(
        min + 7 * step, (253, 174, 97), min + 8 * step, (244, 109, 67)
    )
    colors.CreateColorRamp(
        min + 8 * step, (244, 109, 67), min + 9 * step, (213, 62, 79)
    )
    colors.CreateColorRamp(min + 9 * step, (213, 62, 79), max, (158, 1, 66))

    return colors

def generate_heatmap(north, south, east, west):
    relevant_dem_files = get_relevant_dem_files()

    # Crop the VRT to the size of the viewport on the client
    opts_list = ["-te {} {} {} {}".format(west, south, east, north)]

    opts = " ".join(opts_list)
    vrt = gdal.BuildVRT("vrtCropped.vrt", relevant_dem_files, options=opts)

    # Get the min and max elevation in the data set so a relative heatmap can be generated
    stats = vrt.GetRasterBand(1).GetStatistics(True, True)

    min = round(stats[0])
    max = round(stats[1])
    step = round((max - min) / 10)

    # Apply the colour ramp
    colors = get_color_map(min, max, step)
    vrt.GetRasterBand(1).SetRasterColorTable(colors)
    vrt.GetRasterBand(1).SetRasterColorInterpretation(gdal.GCI_PaletteIndex)

    options_string = " ".join(
        [
            "-b 1",
            "-ot Byte",
            "-expand rgb",
        ]
    )

    gdal.Translate("MergedDEMCropped.jpg", vrt, options=options_string)
```

The result:

[image]

Using a fixed color ramp and `gdal.Warp` the color ramp wouldn't be applied above a certain elevation either.